# Python: Write when reading a file

Tags: python, file

I have a file in which each line contains a sentence. Some sentences are however empty, i.e. in this case there is just `"\n"` newline character on the line.

What I want to do is: if I find an empty sentence, I want to replace it with some symbol like .

If I replace `"\n"`, it will be replaced at all places in the file.

However, I am not sure how to do this:

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], "wr")

for line in f:
    if len(line.strip())==0:
        line.replace("\n", "empty")
         # Then write the line back on the file
        f.write(line + "\n") # Will this replace the line in the file?
```

Is the above code correct? Can I simultaneously read the line and edit it too?

Comment: Don't forget to `close` your file! Or use it in a `with` context.

Comment: `if not line.strip(): line = '.\n'` will change all lines that are empty or just contain whitespace characters.

Comment: Nothing here currently writes back changes to the file, which I'm *assuming* is something you want to do. Might want to make the question explicit on that point? Also, it makes a very big difference whether you want to operate in-place, or can just read the whole thing into memory and rewrite from the beginning. UNIX in-place file operations just allow byte-for-byte replacement; you can't replace a string with one that's longer or shorter than the original.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, that's why I asked the question, will just writing f.write() work here? how to handle the specific problem above?

Comment: `'wr'` is not a valid mode for opening files. It has to be one or the other, or `'a'`

Comment: Which specific problem?

Comment: `f.write()` will work, but you need to be sure to `seek()` to the specific place where you want that write to start beforehand.

Comment: @isaactfa, you're leaving off a number of possible modes (`r+`, f/e).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, but they are all just variations on read/write/append, which are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the specific problem is: in the above way of reading the file how to write the updated line so that it replaces the earlier line? also which mode is suited for this..

Comment: @isaactfa, read and write are not mutually exclusive. `O_RW` is, at the syscall layer, a thing; and `r+` passes it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair enough, I was just trying to put simply what Python tells you, when you have more than one of `w`/`r`/`a` in your mode. `ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick way of solving the problem, but not the ideal way of doing it should you have memory constrictions.

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

lines = ['empty' if i == '\n' else i for i in lines]
f = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

Should you have memory restrictions, creating a function utilising `yield` would be the best way to go about this

Edit: I should also say unless there has been an update, I don't believe it is possible to overwrite a specific line in a file using python without re-writing the entire file.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to overwrite a single line in-place, *so long as the replacement line is the same length as the original*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how would you do that?

Comment: `seek()` to the byte offset where the line starts, then `write()` the new value (after opening the file `r+` so writing is allowed).

Comment: I never found that to work in practice, I guess it's because of the "same length" thing you described

Comment: *nod* -- each byte you write overwrites a single byte of the preexisting content, so if you write something shorter than the original line, the end of the former one is still there; write something longer, and you start to overwrite the beginning of the next line.